# Gerar arquivo PDF com rodapé apenas na última página usando o mPDF v 5

Tags: php, mpdf

Gostaria de uma ajuda com o `mPDF`. Estou tentando configurar um rodapé sempre na última página e gostaria de saber se isso é possível. Os arquivos poderão conter 1, 2 ou mais páginas, mas preciso que rodapé apareça **apenas na última página**.

Answer (score -1):

Basta instanciar o *method* `SetHTMLFooter()` **depois** do `WriteHTML()`, como no código abaixo:

```
<?php

require_once '/usr/share/php/mpdf/mpdf-5.7.4a/mpdf.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf();

$html = '<table class="table-body">';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $html.='<tr>
    <td width="30.3%">Forbrug '.$i.'</td>
    <td width="23.1%">Periode '.$i.'</td>
    <td width="10.76%">'.$i.' MB</td>
    <td width="9.28%">Val '.$i.'</td>
    <td width="12.9%" align="right">I alt '.$i.'</td>
    <td width="13.3%" align="right"><b>moms</b> '.$i.'</td>
    </tr>';
}
$html.= '</table>';$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');   
$footer = "<table width=\"1000\" border=\"1\">
<tr>
<td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">{PAGENO}</td>
</tr>
</table>";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer); /* Aplicando o rodapé apenas na última página */
$mpdf->Output();
```

Se `SetHTMLFooter()` aparecer **antes** de `WriteHTML()`, o rodapé será aplicado a todas as páginas do documento.

No exemplo, usei a versão `5.7.4a`.